# Loading child doesn't load parent

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following entities

```
Parent(
 id PK, 
 name VARCHAR
 //more fields
);
```

And my child table is

```
Child(
   id PK, 
   parentId FK, 
   name VARCHAR
);
```

in my java entities my parent is defined as

```
@Entity
class Parent{
   @Id
   private int id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parents")
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Set<Child> children;
}
```

and my Child class is

```
@Entity
class Child{
   @Id
   private int id;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "parendId")
   @JsonManagedReference
   private Parent parent;
}
```

Then I have `ChildRepo` with following method. The method is executing fine but i am getting empty parent.

here is the query

```
@Query("select c from Child c where c.name is not null")
List<Child> getAllChildrenWithName();
```

P.S: I am using `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` to avoid recursion while sending entities back via Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query to the following:

```
@Query("select c from Child c LEFT JOIN c.parent p where c.name is not null")
```

If you use inner join your query result might be null if the children are not associated to a parent.

Comment: shouldn't the parent be lazy loaded later even if there was no left join?